# Why does Command.output() execution sometimes return None for status.code()

Tags: rust

My rust project uses `Command` to execute a process.

Sometimes (low frequency) when I run this code the call to `status.code()` returns None. I am usually using Mac OS Catalina Beta 1, rustc 1.36.0 - but it happens in Travis too (will have to go and find logs of OS/rustc there).

I was treating this as an error but "randomly" it would cause local and travis builds to fail, so now I'm ignoring it - but it would be nice to understand what's causing it.

In failure cases, re-running immediately will cause it to succeed.

```rust
let output = Command::new(&command)
    .args(command_args)
    .stdin(Stdio::inherit())
    .stdout(Stdio::inherit())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .output()
    .chain_err(|| "Error while attempting to spawn command to compile and run flow")?;
match output.status.code() {
    Some(0) => Ok("Flow ran to completion".to_string()),
    Some(code) => {
        error!(
            "Process STDERR:\n{}",
            String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stderr)
        );
        bail!("Exited with status code: {}", code)
    }
    None => Ok("No return code - ignoring".to_string()),
}
```

My question is not why this *could* happen (I know that the docs say "terminated by signal") but why it *is* happening, as no-one AFAIK is sending a signal to it, I seriously doubt any OOM or other such issues.

Comment: I wonder what are the OS and Rust version?

Comment: @ArtemGr I didn't find any notable change on https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commits/master/src/libstd/process.rs.

Comment: Sorry - that info SHOULD be in there. adding it in now.... Mac OS Catalina Beta 1, rustc 1.36.0

Answer (score 5):

Read the [manual](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/process/struct.ExitStatus.html#method.code):

> On Unix, this will return `None` if the process was terminated by a signal; `std::os::unix` provides an extension trait for extracting the signal and other details from the `ExitStatus`.

```rust
use std::os::unix::process::ExitStatusExt;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("sleep")
        .args(&["10"])
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn child");
    child.kill().expect("failed to kill on child");
    let status = child.wait().expect("failed to wait on child");
    match status.code() {
        None => {
            println!("{:?}", status.signal());
            ()
        }
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

You could use [`from_c_int()`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.14.1/nix/sys/signal/enum.Signal.html#method.from_c_int) to have a pretty print of the signal type.

Comment: I already had, and my fail logs used to print "Process terminated by signal", but that doesn't help me understand why it's happening, and if a signal where that signal is coming from and why it's being sent.

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie How should I know, first try to see what signal have been receive https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/os/unix/process/trait.ExitStatusExt.html#tymethod.signal.

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie What's sending the signal is something on your system, (very likely) not your own program. Finding this out would be a completely different question and the relevant information would not be your code, but how you're running the program and which signal you're getting. And it would be more of a [unix.se] question than an [so] question.